Ubuntu 24.04 dual boot windows 11, not detecting nvidia drivers
I recently purchased a Dell computer with a Nvidia RTX 4060 pre installed with Windows 11. I installed Ubuntu 24.04 at its side. The installation was a bit erratic since I know close to nothing about the Bios, ... but at the end it seemed to work just fine. (I must mention that I use XFCE). While I was trying to use pytorch I realized that cuda was not detecting my nvidia graphic card. I then used ubuntu-drives to make sure I have the proper nvidia installed, the installation went without trouble. When I use the following commands, it returns:
nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it could'nt communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

modprobe nvidia
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Key was rejected by service

Then I found some people suggesting that I should turn off the boot secure mode, so I did but then when I launch Ubuntu I get a black screen and nothing is working untill I turn the secure boot on again.
Anyone knows what I could try next?
EDIT:
I went to a an other Ubuntu forum where I was asked to give the following command ouptuts, maybe that could help. So far, no solution was found.
lspci -vnn | grep -A 12 '\''[030[02]\]' | grep -Ei "vga|3d|display|kernel"
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-S UHD Graphics [8086:a788] (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915, xe
0000:01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation AD107M [GeForce RTX 4060 Max-Q / Mobile] [10de:28e0] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

uname -a
Linux user-Dell-G16-7630 6.8.0-45-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Aug 30 12:02:04 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ubuntu-drivers devices
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd000028E0sv00001028sd00000BFAbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : AD107M [GeForce RTX 4060 Max-Q / Mobile]
driver   : nvidia-driver-535-open - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-535-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-550-open - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-535-server-open - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-550 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-535 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-550:amd64                      550.107.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-550                          550.107.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1              all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
rc  libnvidia-compute-535:amd64                   535.183.01-0ubuntu0.24.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-550:amd64                   550.107.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-550:amd64                    550.107.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-egl-wayland1:amd64                  1:1.1.13-1build1                         amd64        Wayland EGL External Platform library -- shared library
ii  libnvidia-encode-550:amd64                    550.107.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1              amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-550:amd64                     550.107.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1              amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-550:amd64                      550.107.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-550:amd64                        550.107.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-550                      550.107.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-550                               550.107.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-550                             550.107.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-firmware-550-550.107.02                550.107.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1              amd64        Firmware files used by the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-550                      550.107.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1              amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-550                      550.107.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                                  0.8.17.2                                 all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                               510.47.03-0ubuntu4                       amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-550                              550.107.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  screen-resolution-extra                       0.18.3                                   all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-550                 550.107.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver

dpkg -l | grep -v ^ii
Souhait=inconnU/Installé/suppRimé/Purgé/H=à garder
| État=Non/Installé/fichier-Config/dépaqUeté/échec-conFig/H=semi-installé/W=attend-traitement-déclenchements
|/ Err?=(aucune)/besoin Réinstallation (État,Err: majuscule=mauvais)
||/ Nom                                           Version                                  Architecture Description
+++-=============================================-========================================-============-================================================================================
rc  ca-certificates-java                          20240118                                 all          Common CA certificates (JKS keystore)
rc  java-common                                   0.75+exp1                                all          Base package for Java runtimes
rc  libnvidia-compute-535:amd64                   535.183.01-0ubuntu0.24.04.1              amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64                  8u422-b05-1~24.04                        amd64        OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)

echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11


Hope, the discussion in the below link should help. https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-23-10-windows-dual-boot-secure-rtx-3070-mobile-nvidia-535-or-545-nvidia-driver-will-not-load/277807
